# (C# WPF) How to open menuB when MenuItem in menuA is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem

I want the application to open a second Menu from the Main Menu once the MenuItem has been clicked (by open, I mean menuB is only visible once the item in menuA is clicked). I am not sure what event handler to use to do this, as I tried an IF statement but it does not allow this. I haven't been able to find any help for how to do this.

I am new to WPF so I am not fully sure what I need to add here. I Appreciate any help for this.

XAML:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="ParkingMenu" 
          Header="Parking"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          FontSize="20" Height="55"
          Width="230"
          Background="#FF083061"
          Foreground="White">

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  Height="165">
        <StackPanel>
            <MenuItem x:Name="Park1" 
                      Header="Parking 1"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      FontSize="20"
                      Height="55"
                      Width="230"
                      Background="#FF083061"
                      Foreground="White"
                      Click="Park1_Click"/>
      <StackPanel/>
   <ScrollViewer/>
<MenuItem/>
```

C#:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {

        }

        private void Park1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Park1.IsStylusCaptured == true)
            {
                menuB.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error statement: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement WPFAPP".**

Comment: See my answer on how to create a menu. The error you get is because the `==` operator is a comparison (used in `if` statements etc as a condition). You want to set `menuB.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;`. But again, you don't need to manually set visibility like this. The menu control will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use scroll viewers etc. Simply use `Menu` and `MenuItem` nested to create a nested menu, and `WPF` will take care of showing them when mouse is hovered.

```
<Grid>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Main1">
            <MenuItem Header="Sub1">
                <MenuItem Header="SubSub5"/>
            </MenuItem>                
            <MenuItem Header="Sub2"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Main2">
            <MenuItem Header="Sub3"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub4"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

### Result:

[image]